# Angular - unknown nullinjector error after upgrade from 10 to 13

Tags: angular

I've recently upgraded angular in app from 10 to 13. What I get is some unknown missing provider error which I can't locate in code. Can you give me some clue how to investigate this error call stack and get more specific feedback?
It looks like this:
[image]

I've also tried to bump all dependencies but it didn't help.
Thanks for any help!

Here is package.json

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "13.3.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "13.3.8",
    "@angular/common": "13.3.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.3.10",
    "@angular/core": "13.3.10",
    "@angular/forms": "13.3.10",
    "@angular/material": "13.3.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.3.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.3.10",
    "@angular/router": "13.3.10",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.24.0",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.8.3",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "5.0.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "5.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.22.7",
    "core-js-bundle": "3.6.5",
    "cypress-real-events": "^1.7.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.2",
    "dayjs-plugin-utc": "^0.1.2",
    "dayjs-timezone-iana-plugin": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-viewport": "^1.0.9",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^13.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.7",
    "@angular/cli": "13.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.3.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.0-next.1",
    "copyfiles": "2.4.1",
    "cypress": "5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
    "karma": "6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `T0` in your code?

Comment: I have no clue. After some changes T0 changed to S0... This error literally don't tell anything :(

Comment: mmm maybe, is something in your spec.ts files. can you try to comment all test, and try again?

Comment: could be a version mismatch please post you package.json

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I've added package.json to main post

Comment: Are you running this in production mode? If so can you try to reproduce the error with 
a debug build? That should give you an error with non-obfusicated names for T0

Comment: @Igor that helped a little. At least I know from which component it's called. Hope I'll find a cause. Thanks!

Comment: You need to update you ngx loading bar to version 6.x its the mismatch you are having pretty sure based on their own gihub readme page https://github.com/aitboudad/ngx-loading-bar

Comment: Fortunately, I've found problem. There was missing provider for angular material (something could change when upgrading material from 10 to 13, because earlier this provider wasn't required and everything worked fine). Thanks for support, I didn't know there is chance to display from which component error call stack starts in prod bundle. That worked like a charm!